# Animate Timer in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, uiviewanimation

I'm looking for an efficient way to animate an Timer which uses an UILabel.
The animation of the timer should be something like the higher number coming up from above on the old label.

I know how to do the animation but how can I make sure that it takes the exact time of one second?(It should be accurate).

Currently I'm updating my label with an NSTimer that is called every 0.5seconds with the current NSDate. This is necessary so that the user can close the app and the timer "continues".

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self 
                                                selector:@selector(refreshTimeLabel:) 
                                                userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Are there any suggesting how to provide an exact to second counting UILabel which increments with an animation?

Comment: Can you explain better what does "This is necessary so that the user can close the app and the timer "continues"." mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take one integer variable in .h file

```
int seconds;
```

and in viewDidLoad in .m file

```
seconds = 0;
```

and start your timer below it

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self 
                                            selector:@selector(refreshTimeLabel:) 
                                            userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)refreshTimeLabel:(id)sender
{
    seconds++;
    lblDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",seconds];
}
```

and you said that you know how to do animation so just use your animation for setting lable on above method best of luck :)